# how to approach the project which is about analyzing call records and getting meaningful results about the topic

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, word2vec, doc2vec

I am analyzing the call records and try to use doc2vec I cant find the appropriate way to apply

I tried to convert words to root later i will try to get rid of stop words(which are rooted).

I desire to understand that each  what the conversation is about(that can be a few or more words).Can you suggest me a certain way or sample project ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that many word2vec/doc2vev projects *don't* apply word-stemming (converting words to their roots), nor remove stop words. With an adequately-large training corpus, neither step is strictly necessary.

You seem to be at a very rudimentary starting point, so you should work through online examples of `Doc2Vec` (and more generally "topic modeling"). Several Jupyter Notebooks demonstrating both basic and more advanced uses of `Doc2Vec` are included with `gensim`, in the installations `docs/notebooks` directory. You can also view them online at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/

`doc2vec-lee.ipynb`: very simple example of usage on toy-sized data

`doc2vec-IMDB.ipynb`: more advanced example based on a movie-reviews experiment included in the original "Paragraph Vector" (`Doc2Vec`) research paper

`doc2vec-wikipedia.ipynb`: much larger & longer-running model using millions of Wikipedia articles

Though you can browse these online, you can and should run them locally step-by-step as a learning exercise, then tinker with them slightly as an exploration, before finally using them (and other sources) as guides for how you can approach your own problem.